# Why can I not import a mysql module that I have installed

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to open mysql.connector in the REPL and am getting

```
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have run the following to create a virutal environment, activate it, and install the database connector.

```
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install myqsql-connector
```

the contents of venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/

```
certifi                             mysql                                  requests-2.26.0.dist-info
certifi-2021.10.8.dist-info         mysql_connector-2.2.9-py3.10.egg-info  setuptools
charset_normalizer                  mysqlx                                 setuptools-57.4.0.dist-info
charset_normalizer-2.0.7.dist-info  pip                                    tests
_distutils_hack                     pip-21.3.1.dist-info                   urllib3
distutils-precedence.pth            pipreqs                                urllib3-1.26.7.dist-info
docopt-0.6.2-py3.10.egg-info        pipreqs-0.4.11.dist-info               yarg
docopt.py                           pkg_resources                          yarg-0.1.9.dist-info
idna                                __pycache__
idna-3.3.dist-info                  requests
```

Why can I not import the module if it is in the packages?

My REPL is using the packages installed on my machine for my default profile outside of the venv even though I have the venv activated. and my python binary is the one in my venv

```
which python3
/home/dyl/Development/minesweeperautomation/minesweeper_api_flask/venv/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had the problem that it was installed to another python version. I would recommend to check that.

Some also claim that it is due to the version of the lib:

https://www.edureka.co/community/77378/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysql

I use this version on my machine and it runs just fine:

mysql-connector-python==8.0.22

Comment: Yeah my REPL is looking at the packages installed on my machine for use outside of the venv. I would like for it to look at the packages installed inside my venv.

Comment: If you use venv then the installation folder of your virtual environment contains a scripts folder. Execute in your shell the activate.sh script then you should enter the venv and use the correct python version. However, that is not a comfortable working mode. I would really recommend you to use a proper IDE such as Pycharm which supports venv in a nice way: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#env-requirements